# C# how to check if a string contains 3 times the same letters in a row

Tags: c#, string, row

How can I check whether an array of strings has the same letter three times in a row? for example:

`AABAC` would return no

`AAABC` would return yes

Comment: you should try reading about regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes (rarely) regexes are the response to the question, especially if the question is like this.

```
bool ism1 = Regex.IsMatch("AABAC", @"(.)\1\1"); // false
bool ism2 = Regex.IsMatch("AAABC", @"(.)\1\1"); // true
```

Matches any character (`.`) followed by the first match (`\1`) twice.

Answer (score 4):

```
bool ContainsTheSameCharThreeTimesInARow(string s) {
    for (int i = 2; i < s.Length; ++i) {
        if (s[i] == s[i-1] && s[i] == s[i-2])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just scan through the `string` value and check if three adjacent character are the same

```
public bool Contains3InARow(string data)
{
  for(var i=0;i<data.Length-2;++i)
   if(data[i]==data[i+1] && data[i+1]==data[i+2]) 
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Only thing... Use `.Length` instead of `.Count()`, and it is -2 not -3 I think

Comment: @xanatos nice catch , updated

Answer (score 0):

```
bool CheckStringHasRepeatForThree(string inputString)
{
   if (inputString.Length < 3) return false;
   return inputString.Where((c,i)=> i >= 2 && s[i-1] == c && s[i-2] == c).Any();
}
```